# Curious about wear on an SSD

Tags: windows, ssd

I have found a old ssd, i don't know what any of these SMART values mean, but I'm wondering if it's still reliable for day to day use.

I am storing a few things on it and it seems to bench at 200 read/write, it is an odler samsung evo 500gb

```
05  Reallocated Sectors Count   0   100 100 10  0000000000  Good
09  Power-On Hours (POH)    788d 11h    96  96  0   00000049EB  Good
0C  Device Power Cycle Count    2,197   97  97  0   0000000895  Good
B1  Wear Leveling Count         77  96  96  0   000000004D  Good
B3  Used Reserved Block Count (Total)   0   100 100 10  0000000000  Good
B5  Program Fail Count (Total)  0   100 100 10  0000000000  Good
B6  Erase Fail Count (Total)    0   100 100 10  0000000000  Good
B7  Runtime Bad Block (Total)   0   100 100 10  0000000000  Good
BB  Uncorrectable Error Count   0   100 100 0   0000000000  Good
BE  Temperature Exceed Count    29  71  47  0   000000001D  Good
C3  ECC Rate                    0   200 200 0   0000000000  Good
C7  CRC Error Count             0   100 100 0   0000000000  Good
EB  Power Recovery Count        87  99  99  0   0000000057  Good
F1  Total LBAs Written  53,426,388,872  99  99  0   007075FF88  Good
```

Answer (score 0):

Every row reports "Good" so you should be fine. As usual keeping a backup of your valuable data is a good idea, although SSDs often fail into a read-only mode where your data can still be recovered.

Comment: Reading the details is a little tricky. I *think* it is saying that there have been no Reallocated Sectors which is a good sign.